# the position of 'annually' in the 'as much amount of soybeans as' sentence

Tags: adverbs

If you were to say the annual consumption of soybeans by one American is about the same as that by one Canadian, where would you place ***annually***?

[1] One American consumes about as much amount of soybeans as one Canadian ***annually***.

[2] One American consumes about as much amount of soybeans ***annually*** as one Canadian.

Comment: Although both your options are easily understood (because the reader automatically guesses that the term "annually" applies to both, there are better options - see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

It is best to place the "annually" at the start, because it then applies unambiguously to both groups:

- "Annually, one American consumes ....**

Please also note that "as much amount" is incorrect.  The phrase should be:

- "... about the same amount as ..".

Further, to be technically correct, you should refer to the figures as being averages, although you then need to check what type of average.

Overall, some possible rephrasings would be as follows.

- "Annually, the average American consumes the same amount of soybeans as the average Canadian."
- "The average annual per capital consumption of soybeans is the same in the US and Canada."

The second option would be appropriate if you were writing for a technical audience (e.g. for a government publication on the state of the economy). The first might be better if you were writing for the general public (e.g. for a newspaper article reporting on the above publication).